# Conditional include js/css files for IE with meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

In pure html it is common to use conditional includes like:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ltie9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

My ltie9.js is pretty simple

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ltie9").modal('show');
});
```

The ltie9.js is wrapped by meteor into:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/client/js/ltie9.js?dbe4ceed5fdf7ec4fd714612d501c94e5c19c04b"></script>
```

Wrapped as it looks now:

```
(function(){$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ltie9").modal('show');
});
})();
```

Seems that conditional comment doesn't work as the modal occurs even if I use Chrome. How to fix that conditional statement - should I check the browser vendor and version via js? Sounds like a very heavy solution.

Comment: To precise the ltie9.js is under /client/js/ directory - probably this causes the issue and I'm doing something in a wrong way. If I move the script into /public/js/ then it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any .js files in /client will simply be included in your codebase - you should not try to included them manually in the head.

To do what you're looking to do, keep the conditional comment but place the JS file in the /public folder where they will be treated as static content (and not part of your application code).

Comment: Thank you for clarification and confirmation. Yes indeed, from the /public folder it works well.